# jQuery is not defined in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento2

I'm create a `require.js` file in my custom theme when I try to load a custom js `library`.

**CODE JS: (requirejs-config.js)**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'demo': 'js/vendor/demo/demo'
        }
    },

    deps: [
        'demo'
    ]
};
```

I load `require.js` and `require-config.js` in `<head>`

**CODE XML: (default.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <block name="require.js" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::page/js/require_js.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
        <link src="requirejs/require.js"/>
        <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**CODE PHTML: (require_js.phtml)**

```
<script>
    var BASE_URL = '<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBaseUrl()) ?>';
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('/')) ?>"
    };
</script>
```

Everything is ok, `js` files are loaded in  but the problem is the next error I get

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

the order in which the items are loaded I post in the image below
[image].

I don't understand why error occurs, `jQuery` is declared before `demo.js`

Do you have any suggestions on this problem and how it can be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add the code from demo.js for anyone to debug it. While jquery is loaded before demo.js, it is available through require.js and it's `require([...], function(...) {});`, not globally. That may be enough for you to figure it out yourself anyway with a bit of googling.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the scripts you load will be modules that are defined by calling define(). However, you may need to use some traditional/legacy "browser globals" scripts that do not express their dependencies via define(). For those, you can use the shim config. To properly express their dependencies.
You need to add jQuery dependency in shim config in your require.js file as follows:

```
 var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'demo': 'js/vendor/demo/demo'
        }
    },
   shim: {
        demo: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```